# Show all text document

Tags: html, css, embed

I have a document that I want to have on my page, however it is in a small box. I want to know how show it all at once instead of someone having to scroll down in a small box. Here is what i have:

```
<p><object src="resume.html"><embed src="resume.html"></embed></object></p>
```

Would I have to change something in the CSS or in the HTML? If you could give me the answer using CSS that would be great. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can change either the HTML or the CSS.

**HTML:**

The  object has a height="" attribute, so you can just set the height to whatever size you want the object to be. (It has a width="" attribute as well, should the need arise)

```
<embed src="resume.html" height="400px">
```

**CSS:**

A bit more complicated. You'll first want to link to an external stylesheet, like so:

```
<head>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="application.css"> 
</head>
```

And add classes to the items for proper CSS syntax:

```
<object class="outer" src="resume.html">
<embed class="inner" src="resume.html"></embed></object>
```

In your CSS, you just call the class and set its height attribute to whatever you want. You can use absolute height, specifying the number of pixels that you want. However, it is probably better practice to specify the height relatively, as a percentage of the height of its parent element. So your CSS would look something like this:

```
.inner {
    height: 100%;
}
```

In this case, 100% will make it the same height as the element surrounding it, and will make it show up as you want it to.